# How do I create a criteria query multiselect with a list

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-criteria

Suppose I have a Teacher class with a list of students, I want to write a multiselect that gets some properties from the class Teacher and a list of students name with score > 15 for example,
So I want to have a constructor that matches the multiselect in this way for example

```
public TeacherDTO(String name, String course, List<String> studentNames) {
    this.name = name;
    this.course = course;
    this.studentNames = studentNames;
}
```

So how do I write the multiselect to get this ? This is what I wrote but I get a line for each student

```
    final Root<Teacher> root = criteriaQuery.from(Teacher.class);
    final Join<Teacher, Student> join = root.join(Teacher_.students, JoinType.LEFT);
    join.on(builder.isGreaterThanOrEquals(join.get(Student_.score), 15));
    
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(
        root.get(Teacher_.name),
        root.get(Teacher_.course),
        join.get(Student_name));
```

Comment: Unless you are returning entities which are a special case that allow providers to perform other queries in the background if needed to build them (and have the info available to know how to group the data), you can't return formed collections from queries. All you could do is get the raw data and group it yourself to form the java objects.

Comment: Student is an entity too, but I want to return a list of them, I was thinking it's impossible but I wanted to ask so I can be sure